# PineScript - Setting up Color Inputs for variables

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, pine-script-v4

I just added a simple EMA script to my strategy. The problem is when it loads up, the color defval is blue. So I made color inputs for each ema (Slow and Fast), but it is not working. Do you know where I made the mistake?

Ema script:

```
// EMA input
var emacross = "EMA Cross"
ema_01_len = input(20, title='Fast EMA', step=1, type=input.integer, group = emacross)      
ema_02_len = input(50, title='Slow EMA', step=1, type=input.integer, group = emacross)
ema_src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=close, group = emacross)

plot_fastEma = input(title="PLot Fast Ema", type=input.bool, defval=false,group=emacross)
plot_slowEma = input(title="PLot Slow Ema", type=input.bool, defval=false,group=emacross)

// EMA def
ema_01 = ema(ema_src, ema_01_len)
ema_02 = ema(ema_src, ema_02_len)

//Plot Emas
plot(plot_fastEma ? ema_01 :an)
plot(plot_slowEma ? ema_02 :an)

// Plot Ema Colors
col_ema01 = input(#2962FF, "Fast EMA", group="Color Settings", inline="EMA FAST",group=emacross)
col_ema02 = input(#FF6D00, "Slow EMA", group="Color Settings", inline="EMA SLOW", group=emacross)
```

- Also is there a way to set a color defval so when the indicator opens up it shows specific colors? (ex:Orange,Red)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you are not using the input variables (`col_ema01` and `col_ema02`) you created.

`plot()` has a `color` parameter that you can use to set default colors to plots.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
plot(series=close, title="Close plot", color=color.orange)
```

You actually don't need any user input for the color because you can easily change the color via style settings of the indicator.

[image]

Comment: so I actually wanted this input for my strategy. The strategy is a  long script and I wanted to have a separate input for the color of this specific function. so according to your method, I removed "col_ema01" and "col_ema02" and I just inserted "color=color.orange'' into "plot_fastEma" and "plot_slowEma", but I get the error of "Unknown argument 'color' of type 'const color''. or I should have done differently?

Comment: Please share a minimum amount of code that reproduces your problem. But again, you can change the color of any plot via settings, why do you want to have it a user input?